# ¿Como darle formato a las celdas de excel con php sin librerías?

Tags: php

Tengo una problema cuando genero mi excel, sale todo bien sólo que algunos campos en mi excel no imprimen correctamente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como puede ver sale `+11`

¿Cómo puedo solucionar eso?

cuando le doy formato `number` sale bien pero dentro del excel necesito que se mande así.

Espero su ayuda gracias.

**Sin librerias, porfavor.**

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('America/Lima');

$fecha = $_GET['fecha'];
$distrito = $_GET['distrito'];
$idestadob = $_GET['idestadob'];

$where =" where 1=1 and v.idestado_venta IN(3,4,5,6) "; 
        //$where = "where 1=1 and ";
        if(!empty($distrito)){
                    $where =$where." and v.idistrito='$distrito' ";

        }
                if(!empty($fecha)){
                    $where =$where." and v.fecha_entrega='$fecha' ";

        }

$sql="SELECT v.idventa as ID, v.codigo_unico as Codigo,v.completo as Cliente,v.telefono as Telefono,te.tipoentrega as Entrega, 
                        d.nombre as Distrito, d.costo_delivery, v.total as Total,
                            DATE_FORMAT(v.fecha_entrega,'%d-%m-%Y') as fecha_entrega, ve.descripcion as Estado
                        FROM VENTA v
                        LEFT JOIN TIPO_ENTREGA te ON v.idtipoentrega = te.idtipoentrega
                        LEFT JOIN TIPO_PAGO tp ON v.idtipopago = tp.idtipopago
                        LEFT JOIN TIPO_COMPROBANTE tc ON v.idtipocomprobante = tc.idtipocomprobante
                        LEFT JOIN DISTRITO d ON v.idistrito = d.idistrito 
                        LEFT JOIN VENTA_ESTADO ve ON ve.idestado_venta = v.idestado_venta
                            $where
                            ORDER BY v.fecha_entrega DESC";


$xls_filename = 'pedido'.date('Y-m-d').'.xls'; 
$result =  @mysqli_query($Connect, $sql) or die("Failed to execute query:<br />" . mysqli_error($Connect). "<br />" . mysqli_errno($Connect));
 header("Content-Type: application/xls");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$xls_filename");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
 $sep = "\t";

 while ($fieldinfo=mysqli_fetch_field($result))
    {
    printf ($fieldinfo->name);
    echo "\t";
 }

print("\n");
// End of printing column names

// Start while loop to get data
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))

    {
      $schema_insert = "";
      for($j=0; $j<mysqli_num_fields($result); $j++)
      {
    if(!isset($row[$j])) {
      $schema_insert .= "NULL".$sep;
    }
    elseif ($row[$j] != "") {
      $schema_insert .= "$row[$j]".$sep;
    }
    else {
      $schema_insert .= "".$sep;
    }
  }
  $schema_insert = str_replace($sep."$", "", $schema_insert);
  $schema_insert = preg_replace("/\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r/", " ", $schema_insert);
  $schema_insert .= "\t";
  print(trim($schema_insert));
  print "\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: ¿Por qué no puedes usar librerías?, no hay que reinventar la rueda, a no ser que tengas una razón verdaderamente de peso.

Comment: intenta esto: https://stackoverflow.com/a/354574/5695795 si funciona dime para agregar la respuesta un ejemplo de mas tipos http://cosicimiento.blogspot.cl/2008/11/styling-excel-cells-with-mso-number.html